# Update an pre-installed Android App without Google Play and not to be detected as an unknown source

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on a specific Android app that might not be able to be uploaded to Google play due to some commercial considerations (But will be built in our customized ROM)

And now we've found some ways to update the app without Google Play, but still those solutions will lead to a dialog that asks user to allow installing apps from unknown sources, however showing the dialog and changing the configuration might not be a favorable option for our project.

I've referred to this before
[How to push updates to preinstalled apps without allowing installation from unknown sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263928/how-to-push-updates-to-preinstalled-apps-without-allowing-installation-from-unkn?rq=1) 
Unfortunately our app cannot be built as a system app, so this solution might not be helpful.

So is it possible to update a pre-installed app without Google Play and also not to be detected as unknown sources(Or not be asked by the system)? Thx

Comment: Anything apart from Google Play Store is unknown source for the device. You can still use third party applications like Beta by Crashlytics to manage your releases among your selected users.

Comment: For security reason this should not be possible to make life for maleware authors more difficuilt. Is there any non-malware reason why you need this?

Comment: On second thought, I think that's right, it does cause some security issues, maybe I'll just try some alternatives, thank you all.